# How to sort data 2 times simultaneously in C/C++

Tags: c, sorting

I want to sort data of my file 2 times :

1. According to weather,
2. According to the day.

Now here's the crunch :
 I want to sort the data first by weather, and then keep it static(constant) & sort according to day.

Example :
My data file contains :

```
Sunday Humid

Wednesday Hot

Friday Rainy

Saturday Dry

Monday Wet

Tuesday Dry

Thursday Cloudy
```

---

So After Dual sorting it looks like this :

```
Thursday Cloudy

Tuesday Dry

Saturday Dry

Wednesday Hot

Sunday Humid

Friday Rainy

Monday Wet
```

---

I have tried many things, and nothing worked ~sighs~
have been busy on this for 12-15 days :/

I'm working in C language, & here's my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
           typedef struct {
                           char day[10], weather[10];
                          } daydata;

daydata record[30],temp;
FILE *fp,*ft;
char line[121];

char *item;
int reccount =0, k, i, j, n=0,ch;


fp = fopen("we.txt","r");

while(fgets(line,120,fp))
{

    item = strtok(NULL," ");
    strcpy(record[reccount].day,item);

    item = strtok(NULL,"\n");
    strcpy(record[reccount].weather,item);

    printf("%s\n",record[reccount].day);
    reccount++;
}

fclose(fp);

printf("Weather Record \n\n");
for(k=0;k<reccount;k++)
{
printf("It is %s\n",record[k].weather);
}

    fp = fopen("we.txt","r");
    ft = fopen("sort.txt","w");

    while(fgets(lyne,120,fp) != NULL)
            {
                n++;
            }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%s%s",record[i].day,record[i].weather);

    do {
    ch=0;
    for (j=0; j<n-1; j++){
        if (strcmp(record[j].weather, record[j + 1].weather) > 0) {
        temp = record[j];
        record[j] = record[j + 1];
        record[j + 1] = temp;
            ch=1;
        }

    }
} while (ch); 

 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  fprintf(ft,"\n %s \t %s",record[i].day,record[i].weather);
}

fclose(fp);
fclose(ft);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_I have tried many things_" -- Please show us your attempts even if they don't work.

Comment: And pick **a** language.

Comment: Have a look at sorting algorithm a pick a stable one.

Comment: Have used structured-array. Is it possible to sort structure directly ?
& if so how?

Comment: It doesn't even matter if it's stable or not, either kind will get you a valid sort.

Comment: Look for sorting algorithms or library functions that allow sorting by multiple keys.

Comment: Have updated the post with my coding.... lost the sorting, hence tried to only sort once :/ –

Answer (score 2):

This is extremely trivial, simply write a comparator that compares the weather, and if that's equal, it compares the day instead:

```
int compare(S *a, S* b)
{
  int res = strcmp(a->weather, b->weather);
  return res==0 ? strcmp(a->day, b->day) : res; 
}
```

This can't have possibly taken you *two weeks*.

Comment: Exactly, performing the sort twice does not make sense at all, unless you want to see both results.

Comment: Have updated the post with my coding....
lost the sorting, hence tried to only sort once :/